# Stacking images transparently on top of an background image

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision

What would be an optimal way to stack the following two images:

[image]

[image]

on top of for example such a background so that the black pixels on the two inputs would be transparent? Alpha blending was my initial approach, but since I have the images that I would need to stack on the background are numpy arrays without the alpha channel that became quite a problem.

This is the background layer on which the other images need to be stacked.

[image]

This is the expected result:

[image]

Comment: At least make them the same size if you want folk to help you! Also, what's the third image you provide - is it the (presumably) incorrect result you currently get, or the actual result you would like?

Comment: There is no information in the alpha channel of either of your input images so how can they possibly have enough information to produce the third one? You appear to make an entire building floor plan out of just 11 small rectangles.

Comment: The last image is the one for which I want to stack the two with the black backgrounds. Also, they're all the same size, one just has a white background so it looks smaller here.

Comment: I have edited your question - hopefully it now correctly represents what you are asking. if not, please re-edit.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import cv2

# Load all three images - "c" is the background
a= cv2.imread('a.png')
b= cv2.imread('b.png')
c= cv2.imread('c.png')

# Chop all to same size as smallest
a=a[:632,:474]
b=b[:632,:474]
c=c[:632,:474]

# Mask where a is not black, and copy those bits to c
mask = np.all(a[...,:]>0,axis=2)
c[mask]=a[mask]

# Mask where b is not black, and copy those bits to c
mask = np.all(b[...,:]>0,axis=2)
c[mask]=b[mask]

Your result is now in "c"
```

[image]

Comment: Since ```cv2.imread()``` reads the image with rgb channels, how would this work with an array of shape (n, m) instead of (n, m, c)?

Comment: Nvm you can just use ```mask = a[...,:] > 0``` instead of ```mask = np.all(a[...,:]>0,axis=2)```. Thanks!

Comment: In greyscale, you can just use `mask = a > 0`.